# Tag synonyms between node.js and nodejs

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I do not have the reputation on this site to create a tag synonym, so I am suggesting one here between:

- [node.js](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/node.js)
- [nodejs](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/nodejs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The synonym proposal system doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Whaddya mean? Meta works fine :-)

Comment: Yes... That's what I mean.